# How to install updated version of nanopb along with Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, nanopb

I am trying to update, Firebase version to 8.4.0 and running into following error. To update, I specified the Firebase/Core, Firebase/Crashlytics, Firebase/Performance's version to 8.4.0 in my pod file. Now, when running pod install, I got following error.

```
 Firebase/Crashlytics (~> 8.4.0) was resolved to 8.4.0, which depends on
  FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 8.4.0) was resolved to 8.4.0, which depends on
    nanopb (~> 2.30908.0)
```

I tried the solution that is provided online - `rm -rf Podfile.lock`, but no luck.
Any idea, how to update nanopb too. Or what could be some other probable solutions.

Comment: Delete "Podfile.lock" and re-install your pod. Is there any reason to install particular version?

Comment: The reason is to install the latest one

Comment: The latest Firebase SDK version is  ~> iOS 8.7.0

Comment: okay, the thing is I am having issues upgrading firebase from 6.7. It keeps giving me the same nanopb dependency error. I tried your suggestion but still no luck

Comment: Last suggestion would be, Update your System CocoaPods, Next delete all pod file and repository from your project, Init new Pod file and install fresh one.(Note: Try it in duplicate folder)

Comment: Di accordingly still no luck.

Comment: I just tried to install pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', "8.4.0" It says same issue as you mentioned. Just remove version type and install. It works. ( pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics')

Comment: does it install firebase 8.7.0? Can you check the version number?

Comment: I tried on a new project and yes it works, but I did to make it work for existing project which was using version 6.7. The existing solution online to do "rm -rf Podfile.lock" and then did "pod install". It doesn't work.

Comment: Please share the Podfile

Comment: No required to update nanopb. nanopb is a Message Parser used by google. Just update cocoapods in system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, The reason for Firebase not taking update in my existing project is another framework that has dependency on a lower of version of nanopb(1.30905.0).

I got the hint from paulb777's comment - "Examine Podfile.lock to see the dependency requirements. Not all pods allow their dependencies to update to latest." from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4994

That is the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Any type of files(Podfile.lock) or folders can be delete by below mentioned process:

1. rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock (To delete Pods and Podfile.lock)
2. rm -rf Podfile.lock (Delete only one file)
3. sudo rm -rf some_dir (If permission denied)
4. We can move file to trash folder,
   i.  brew install trash (If not available)
   ii. trash -rf Podfile.lock
5. We have ultimate option to delete a file. **We can delete manually, Select file and move to bin.**

[image]

**Regarding Firebase installation :**

There is a dependancy on Firebase installation on cocoapods(pods).

Firebase 8.2.0 can be installed on pod 1.10.1+. If we try to install Firebase 8.3.0 or above on pod 1.10.1, We will get an error "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions".

If latest pod is not available, Update with latest cocoapods.

'sudo gem install cocoapods --pre'

If available pod(version 1.11.2), We can install any Firebase versions (Example - 8.7.0) without any issue.

Podfile:

[image]

After Pod installation:
[image]

Comment: When I install on a freshly created project, it works as expected. However, when I am doing on my project, it is not working as expected. The cocoa pods version on my system is 1.11.2.