# Flutter CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore"

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I am trying to build an IOS flutter project but it is keep complaining about the compatible versions for pod. I have already tried many threads since last two days but not able to resolve the issue. However my Android version is working fine.

I tried to delete **podfile.lock, podfile, pod** folder, **Runner.xcworkspace** also but nothing works. Now I am not having the **podfile.lock** file anymore. I mean the **podfile.lock** is not getting created.

I am on macOS Big Sur version 11.6.

MacBook Pro 2019

Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core intel Core i9

in my Podfile:

```
       platform :ios, '10.0'
```

I also tried the following commands:

```
   sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

   arch -x86_64 pod install
```

When I run the **pod install** command I am getting the following error.

```
        Analyzing dependencies
        cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        cloud_functions: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_in_app_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '7.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
        [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
        In Podfile:
            firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 0.7.0, which depends on
            Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
                FirebaseCore (= 7.3.0)

            firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
            Firebase/Database (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
                FirebaseDatabase (~> 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
                FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)

            google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
            GoogleMLKit/LinkFirebase (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                MLKitLinkFirebase (~> 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
                FirebaseCore (~> 8.0)

        CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":
        In Podfile:
            firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 7.0.1, which depends on
            Firebase/Analytics (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
                Firebase/Core (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
                FirebaseAnalytics (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
                    GoogleAppMeasurement (= 7.3.0)

            google_mobile_ads (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mobile_ads/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
            Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 8.5.0) was resolved to 8.5.0, which depends on
                GoogleAppMeasurement (< 9.0, >= 7.0)

        CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitCommon":
        In Podfile:
            google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
            GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                GoogleMLKit/MLKitCore (= 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                MLKitCommon (~> 3.0.0)

            google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
            GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 1.3.0) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
                MLKitCommon (~> 3.0)

            google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
            GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                MLKitPoseDetectionAccurate (~> 1.0.0-beta4) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta5, which depends on
                MLKitCommon (~> 3.1)

        CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MLKitXenoCommon":
        In Podfile:
            google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
            GoogleMLKit/PoseDetection (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                MLKitPoseDetection (~> 1.0.0-beta4) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta5, which depends on
                MLKitXenoCommon (= 1.0.0-beta5)

            google_ml_kit (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_ml_kit/ios`) was resolved to 0.6.0, which depends on
            GoogleMLKit/PoseDetectionAccurate (~> 2.2.0) was resolved to 2.2.0, which depends on
                MLKitPoseDetectionAccurate (~> 1.0.0-beta4) was resolved to 1.0.0-beta4, which depends on
                MLKitXenoCommon (= 1.0.0-beta4)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943260/how-do-i-resolve-the-pod-install-error-on-flutter) thread too, but did not work for me...

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69248774/6681858

Answer (score 24):

Please Try this steps :

**if you have intel chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder throuh terminal and do 'pod repo update'
5. 'pod update' or 'pod install'

**if you have M1 chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder throuh terminal and do 'arch -x86_64 pod repo update'
5. 'arch -x86_64 pod update' or 'arch -x86_64 pod install'

Comment: I just identified that my Macbook Pro is running on Intel chip. I tried the first option but it is still giving the same error when I run 'por update' or 'pod install'. My pubspec.yaml has version: 1.0.0+1 and sdk: ">=2.7.0 < 3.0.0"

Comment: @Sam I'm not talking about pubspec.yaml version. I'm talking about all the libraries version like firebase_core, google_ml_kit etc. Please Update latest version and do the steps.

Comment: Thanks Tushar for your reply. Actually when I do "dart pub outdated" it shows me what is the upgradable version for my app (not the latest). I am on the upgradable version itself but yes not on the latest version.

Comment: Thanks, after updating all my dependencies to the latest the problem is gone... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly said that you have a compatibility issue in your cocopod file which may caused when you update the flutter dependencies.You can resolve the issue by reconfiguring the pod files: run these commands.

**Clean the Build and upgrade pod files**

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get
>
> flutter upgrade

**Reinstall Pod files and update**

> cd ios
>
> pod cache clean --all
>
> Pod clean
>
> pod deintegrate
>
> sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
>
> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
>
> arch -x86_64 pod repo update
>
> arch -x86_64 pod install