# Swift Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: Firestore/Protos/nanopb/google/firestore/admin/index.nanopb.h' file not found

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm getting this error even after installing the pods multiple times

```
Swift Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: Firestore/Protos/nanopb/google/firestore/admin/index.nanopb.h' file not found
```

I tried checking the path and the files but nothing seems wrong with it
[image]

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You've got some pods that are no longer required so you may want to re-visit the [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods) note that *The Firebase Core library (Firebase/Core) is no longer needed.*. Along with that, your Cocoapods may be out of date. You should be 1.11 or higher. `pod --version`. Other dependencies may be preventing the pod from updating. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69217195/how-to-install-updated-version-of-nanopb-along-with-firebase/69248774#69248774). Lastly, you may want to deintegrate and then pod install again.

Comment: Add `platform :ios, '10.0'` to the Podfile. 

Recent versions of Firebase require at least iOS 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I check my podfile and define the Firebase SDK version to lasted adding the following to the top of the pod file

```
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.2.0'
```

Comment: Same as @Paul answer, I let this as a comment because could not be the right answer to your problem. I also have defined the iOS version just after the sdk version to prevent compatibility issues ```platform :ios, '11.0'```